# Looped column reference in excel VBA to change for another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy, copy-paste, worksheet

I have VBA code in Excel. I have it looping a column (E2:E100). I want to just copy a cell (the same reference) from one worksheet to another.

```
Sub et()
Dim c As Range
Dim a As Range


Worksheets("CSV2").Select
'//loop it

For Each c In Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlDown))
Set a = Worksheets("CSV").c '// The problem is here. I want the same range selection [c] as worksheet (CSV2) to the worksheet ("CSV") for the range selection [a]. I want to copy directly from [a] to [c]. I want to keep it in this format. Just help with the line here. Thanks.
    
    If c.Value > 0 & c.Value < 3 Then


        Sheets("CSV").Select
        a.Copy'// here I have it to copy the "CSV" sheet
        Sheets("CSV2").Select
        c.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues'// here I want to paste it to the "CSV2" sheet
    End If
   
Next
Worksheets("RETURN").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid selecting sheets and cells ([read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/1521579))

In my code I followed the logic you had about finding the source range through using `End(xlDown)` but you should consider finding the last cell in a row through a different approach ([read this](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba))

Read the code's comments and adjust it to fit your needs

```
Public Sub CopyValues()
    
    ' Set source sheet
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CSV")
    
    ' Set target sheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CSV2")
    
    ' Set source range
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.Range("E2:E" & sourceSheet.Range("E2").End(xlDown).Row)
    
    ' Loop through cells in range
    Dim sourceCell As Range
    For Each sourceCell In sourceRange.Cells
    
        If sourceCell.Value > 0 And sourceCell.Value < 3 Then
            
            ' This is one alternative to paste only values
            targetSheet.Range(sourceCell.Address).Value = sourceCell.Value
            
            ' This is another alternative to paste the cell with value and formats (just comment previous line, and uncomment next to use it)
            'sourceCell.Copy targetSheet.Range(sourceCell.Address)
            
        End If
    
    Next sourcell
    

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: I can't get the `sourceSheet.Range("E2:E" & sourceSheet.Range("E2").End(xlDown))` part of the code to work. Is there any other way (simple if possible) to refer to E2 to end of E column. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah sorry. Missed the `.row`